# LM386 speaker distorts

Tags: amplifier, audio, lm386

I've built an amplifier with an lm386 but when I connect a speaker (8ohm) to the output I get a very distorted signal. The problem appears only when the speaker is connected. If I connect an external amplifier to the lm386 output, the audio is right. 
The issue appears also without gain capacitor between pin 1 and 8 and with the most basic configuration from the datasheet (LM386 with Gain = 20, page 8 on TI datasheet)

How is it possible? [image]

Comment: The schematic shows that the amplifier power supply is 9V/GND, and the incoming AC signal is also referenced to GND.  Is that correct?  What happens when the AC signal goes below GND?

Comment: @scorpdaddy:  If it were connected like the datasheet says to, then it wouldn't matter about the AC going negative.  The LM386 is made to deal with that.  The + input actually has  DC bias on it.  It is **not** an opamp.

Answer (score 4):

Compare your circuit with an example from the [datasheet:](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm386.pdf)

[image]

1. You have the + input grounded rather than the - input as in the datasheet.  The LM386 only works properly when the - is grounded and signal goes in the +.  You have the connections to pin 2 and pin 3 swapped.
2. You have some strange feedback from the output to the gain input.  Don't do that.  The gain pins should only be connected together (through a capacitor or a capacitor in series with a resistor.)  Remove R18 and C9.

---

The LM386 is **not** an opamp.  It is a power amplifier whose symbol happens to resemble that of an opamp.

It doesn't work like an opamp, and you can't treat it as one.

Comment: I used this schematic [link] http://www.circuitbasics.com/build-a-great-sounding-audio-amplifier-with-bass-boost-from-the-lm386/ Using connection to pin 2 and 3 in the right way the out improve slightly but the distortion remains. The only way I found to have a right output is to swap pin 2/3, remove gain capacitor and bass boost, use a 100k resistor on input and a 4.7k resistor from input to ground. The output is very low in this way. The inexplicable thing is that distortion comes out only when a speaker is connected if the output is connected to another amplifier the sound is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using this circuit:

[image]

You should leave pin 8 open in that case, and apply the input signal to pin 3.

If you don't want the bass boost, use one of the other circuits in the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm386.pdf).